# Filter to hook into menu <li> items and add a custom attribute

Tags: menus, filters, customization

I'm using [Foundation](https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress/) as a base and starter theme. I'm trying to build and I can't seem to figure out how to hook into the menu that WordPress outputs and add a custom attribute to that menu's `<li>` tags.

The current menu outputs like this:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="top-bar-menu right">
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item "><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

(*Those links are just there for sample*)

I need WordPress to automatically add the following attribute to the `<li>` tags: `data-magellan-arrival="[target]"`.

`[Target]` needs to automatically be populated by the page_ID that the menu item corresponds to. So for example, let's say that first's `<li><a href="">[PAGE]</a></li>` link is Home and Home's page_ID is "21" (example). I would need `data-magellan-arrival="[target]"` inside of `<li>` to be set to `data-magellan-arrival="21"`.

So it would look like: `<li class="menu-item" data-magellan-arrival="21"><a href="">[PAGE]</a></li>`

I'll be honest with you, I'm not that great at PHP just yet and WordPress filters/hooks much less. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction or show me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can Achieve something similar pretty easy,but also for me was not that easy find an answer. I needed a similar thing for fullpage.js navigation.So i achived like this : i used an alreday existing wordpress menu field that i was not using and i've used its value to fullfil my needs

```
function add_specific_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {

  $atts['data-menuanchor'] = $item->attr_title;


return $atts;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```

inspired by https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes

Answer (score 2):

Please add this function into the `functions.php` file in your theme:

```
function add_attribute( $items, $args ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($items);
    $find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

    foreach ($find as $item ) :
        $item->setAttribute('data-magellan-arrival','21');
    endforeach;

    return $dom->saveHTML();

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_attribute', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score -3):

This looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215797/wordpress-post-id-in-wp-nav-menu) would get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Answers should not rely on external links. This is rather a comment than an answer. Please file an [edit] and post the relevant info inside your answer, keeping the link as reference only